# How to inject a token list dynamically in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a JMeter test with different Tokens to simulate real users. The test works fine with a single Token, but KO when I try to use multiple Tokens with a CSV file.

maybe I did not set the CSV file correctly. 
Can someone help me please, thank you.

Sami.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) for any suspicious entries, in case if JMeter fails to find/open the .CSV file you will see the corresponding message there
2. Check your variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
3. If you don't have too many IDs it might be easier to go for [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)

If you need more assistance we'll need to have:

1. First 2 lines of your CSV file
2. Screenshot of the [CSV data set config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
3. Screenshot of the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) where you're trying to use the variable(s) from the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

2 first lines of mu CSV file :
Bearer eyJtb2QiOiJhY2Nlc3MiLCJraWQiOiJTVD1JTEUgREUgRlJBTkNFLEw9UEFSSVMsQz1GUixDTjkj
Bearer eyJtb2QiOiJhY2Nlc3MiLCJraWQiOiJTVD1JTEUgREUgRlJBTkNFLEw9UEFSSVMsQz1ADOTRPLKH

screen of the CSV data set config :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykxWi.png)